# How to parse a python string json containing a None?

Tags: python, json

How to parse a string json containing a Python None into json object?

JSON string variable

`dummy="{'this':None}"; json.loads(dummy)`

Error if I use json.loads

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes : line 1 and column 2 (char 1)

Next, We replace the single quotes to double quotes.

```
json.loads(dummy.replace("'", '"'))
```

Error after replacing single quotes to double quotes

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 and column 10 (char 9)

How to parse this json string?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You probably shouldn't parse it with a JSON parser. Or, consider replacing `None` with `null` and hope that's the only other error besides the quotes. Of course, doing that naively will also replace `None`s in the JSON strings and keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a JSON. JSON is defined by [json.org](https://www.json.org/) and [RFC8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), and does not recognise single-quoted strings, nor `None`. The JSON equivalent of your data would be `{"this":null}`. Fortunately, it is not just garbage, it is in a format of a Python literal, and can be parsed so:

```
from ast import literal_eval

obj = literal_eval("{'this':None}")
```

Of course, this only works in Python; if you want to interchange this data with other languages, you should use a more standard format (such as e.g. correct JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'this':None}")
{'this': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

> dummy = '{"this": null}';  json_obj = json.loads(dummy)